# android custom view has the error in virtual machine

Tags: android

I write a simple extend view class,the code is following:

```
public class MyView extends View
 {

   public MyView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

     public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }

    protected void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
     {
         super.onDraw(canvas);
     }
 }

XML：
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >


       <com.main.sufaceview.MyView
            android:id="@+id/myview"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/tt"/>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

When entry the virtual machine. It shows the breakdown:
[image]

why this is? i think the custom view should very easy.I did not add other code,it has the error.
Edit:the logcat displays:
[image]

Comment: Can you see any cause to the above exception? Read a bit below the stacktrace you pasted here (also, try to post text instead of a screenshot for a logcat > ctrl + C in the logcat view will copy it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need another constructor, at least, thats what I read in other posts.

```
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```